# flex items overlapping in Safari (iPad)

Tags: ios, css, safari, flexbox

I cannot solve problem with simple task:

- Container is 100% width but with padding-right and box-sizing overflow
- Container is flex row
- Container has two children with dynamic content
- First child has size of content
- Second child takes the rest of width

Expected result:

[image]

iPad result:

[image]

Example is https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zaMwvr

```css
#wrap {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px dashed orangered;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-right: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

#padding-view {
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  background: coral;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#flex {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="padding-view"></div>
  <div id="flex">
    <div id="dynamic">LALALCALCULATEDDYNAMICLY</div>
    <div id="rest">{Long text here}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try adding `flex-shrink: 0` or `min-width: auto` to `.dynamic` ([revised codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eKQGKd)).